# NVIDIA Cuda Power9 setup issue with Ubuntu 20.04: nvidia-persistenced.service is masked

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, cuda

From the Cuda Toolkit Documentation:

> Because of the addition of new features specific to the NVIDIA POWER9
> CUDA driver, there are some additional setup requirements in order for
> the driver to function properly. These additional steps are not
> handled by the installation of CUDA packages, and failure to ensure
> these extra requirements are met will result in a non-functional CUDA
> driver installation. There are two changes that need to be made
> manually after installing the NVIDIA CUDA driver to ensure proper
> operation:

The NVIDIA Persistence Daemon should be automatically started for POWER9 installations. Check that it is running with the following command:

```
 $ systemctl status nvidia-persistenced
```

When I run this command, I get the following:

```
Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit nvidia-persistenced.service is masked.)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

Thanks in advance for your help with this.